# I have to use MID, LEN, and FIND functions in Excel in order to extract a part of an url

Tags: excel, url, find

Good afternoon,

I am not really an Excel champion so I am having a bit of headache with the last assignment my teacher gave me as I have to use three functions at the same time.
Basically I have to extract the urls from B2 and below and be just "www.cocacola.es" in K2 (just ignore column D and E): https://ibb.co/2S36cC0

I was kinda ok at this point: `=MID(B2,FIND("/",B2)+2,LARGO(B2))`

Then I got a little bit lost.
I had a look at the forum as well and I actually ended up finding a solution by adding `-FIND("/",B3)-32))` at the end of the function but it only works for few rows: https://ibb.co/1n0ty8y

I guess it is something related to LEN but I can't figure how to fix it.

Sorry for the dumb question but it's my last work and I really wanna understand it.

Comment: I'm not sure we understand what you're trying to do. If it's extract the "main domain", then personally, for this data, I would find "//" and then "/" (use "//" as the start_num), then Minus the "/" from the "//" and use this as the num_chars. However this wouldn't actually use Len.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want the sub-string between the second **/** and the third **/**.

For all your examples the second **/** is in the eighth position.  So we can use:

```
=MID(MID(A1,9,99),1,FIND("/",MID(A1,9,99))-1)
```

with the full url in **A1**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, the thing is that I must use LEN too as it is specifically requested by the professor. And I am a little bit stuck because unfortunately, as you can see, I am not able to use 3 functions at the same time